# Construct expression tree with chained properties?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have a method that accepts `Expression<Func<T, string>>`, for example `x => x.Name`, and a term, and returns `x => x.Name.Contains(term)`:

Given the model;

```
class X
{
    public Y Y {get; set;}
}

class Y
{
    public string Z {get; set;}
}
```

It works well for `GenerateForMember<Y>(y => y.Z, "foobar")`, but currently don't work for `GenerateForMember<X>(x => x.Y.Z, "foobar")`. It gives the exception

> 'Z' is not a member of 'UserQuery+X'

How to I update my method to work with chained properties?

Method is as follows:

```
protected Expression<Func<T, bool>> GenerateForMember<T>(Expression<Func<T,string>> expression, string term)
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    var memberExpression = ((expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert) 
        ? ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand 
        : expression.Body) as MemberExpression;

    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, type.Name.ToLower());
    MemberExpression member = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, memberExpression.Member.Name);

    var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;

    var memberType = propertyInfo == null
        ? ((FieldInfo) memberExpression.Member).FieldType
        : propertyInfo.PropertyType;


    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(term, typeof(string));

    MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(member, method, constant);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameter);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dissecting the original expression and later re-construct it again. This is not necessary. You can use `expression.Body` directly in order to create the method call. Like this, it should work with any lambda expression.

```
var type = typeof(T);

ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, type.Name.ToLower());

ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(term, typeof(string));

MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(expression.Body, method, constant);

return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameter);
```

Comment: The reason I dissected and reconstructed was because the parameter name might not match. But I was able to rename it using a visitor I already using somewhere else, then use your approach. Thanks.

Comment: @Andre, the approach I suggested reuses the same parameter from the original expression.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Sorry, I was not clear enough. The function that invokes this one might receive more than one member and term, then join them. e.g., passing `x => x.Foo` and `y => y.Bar` and the terms "foo", "bar" results in `x => (x.Foo.Contains("foo") || x.Foo.Contains("bar")) && (x.Bar.Contains("foo") || x.Bar.Contains("bar"))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected Expression<Func<T, bool>> GenerateForMember<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> expression, string term)
{
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(term, typeof(string));

    MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

    var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(expression.Body, method, constant);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsMethodExp, expression.Parameters[0]);
}
```